# Proof related to Hilbert-Schmidt norm

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, normed-spaces

[image]

Hi,

I am very stuck on this proof and I am not sure how to start it. Any help to get started solving it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Prove that operator norm and HS norm of a diagonal matrix $A$ are given by $\|A\| = \max\{|a_{ii}| : i=1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\|A\|_{HS} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}^2}$, respectively. Then the claim follows immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_1,\dotsc, a_n$ be the elements on the diagonal of $A$. First of all prove that
$$
\lVert A \rVert = \max \{ |a_1|, \dotsc, |a_n| \}.
$$

On the other hand
$$
\mathrm{tr}(AA^T) = \mathrm{tr}(A^2) = \sum_{i = 1}^n |a_i|^2.
$$

So
$$
\lVert A \rVert_{HS} = \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n |a_i|^2} \geq \sqrt{\max \{ |a_1|^2, \dotsc, |a_n|^2 \}} = \max \{ |a_1|, \dotsc, |a_n| \} = \lVert A \rVert.
$$

Comment: Exactly as in the comment by @Friedrich Philipp!